# Updating JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

On a program that I am working on, I send a literal variable to local strorage with JSON.stringify. The plan is I want to constantly update the local storage and add onto the existing local storage. I'm getting problems with the parsing aspect of the JSON file. My code for adding to storage is this:

```
function addtoStorage(key, data) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage[key]) {
        console.log("Local Storage stuff" + localStorage[key]);
        var olddata = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
        var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(olddata + data);
        localStorage[key] = localStorage[key] + dataJSON;
    }
    else {
        var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage[key] = dataJSON;
    }
}
else {
    console.log("You don't have storage capabilities. Sorry. Next time improve your browser.");
}
```

}
;

And my output is this on console.log is:

```
Local Storage stuff{"asdf":"","tes":6,"type":"asdf","ast":1,"sd":"","ew":"","asdf":{"te":0,"wer":0},"asf":"","te":"","context":{"asdf":1,"total_hits":0,"asdf":1,"tew":0,"asdf":"","tes":"","date":"asfd-asdf-","asdf":0},"asdf":""}"[object Object][object Object]" main.js:487
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

I'm fairly sure I understand what the problem is. I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it. It is obviously closing out the JSON object too soon, any recommendations???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` is coming from `JSON.parse`, this is because it is no longer valid JSON (http://json.org/)

What you are doing is adding an object to an object, which turns out to be a string

[image]

Then when you go to stringify it, the entire thing will be taken is just a string the first time and the second time. So it will go through fine, then the third time when it tries to parse it, the function will fail because you have added a JSON object with a string.

If you are only storing JSON objects you can use jQuery's extend function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Or if you are storing more then just objects change it all to an array

This should cover everything

```
function addtoStorage(key, data) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
            console.log("Local Storage stuff" + localStorage.getItem(key));
            var olddata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            var newdata = null;
            if(olddata instanceof Array){
                olddata.push(data);
                newdata = olddata;
            }else if(data instanceof Array || !(data instanceof Object) || !(olddata instanceof Object)){
                newdata = [olddata, data];
            }else if(data instanceof Object && olddata instanceof Object){
                newdata = $.extend(olddata, data);
            }
            var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(newdata);
            localStorage.setItem(key, dataJSON);
        }
        else {
            var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
            localStorage.setItem(key, dataJSON);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("You don't have storage capabilities. Sorry. Next time improve your browser.");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Thanks a lot. This answer works which is awesome. In terms of optimization however, this answer rewrites all the data to the localStorage every time. This seems like adding unnecessary operations to the dataStorage. Would there be anyway not to read and extend the entire storage value to increase efficiency?

Comment: Hopefully my question made sense.

Comment: Nah, sorry but the only way you can do this is reading then writing, if you really wanted to do optimizations to it you could keep one object in localStorage for the keys and the other for values, then you could create a map of keys for a single key, then when retrieving the value you could extend it there rather then reading and writing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be doing `olddata + data` since `stringify` is for parsing JavaScript objects to JSON and you can't just add two objects together.

You should try implementing an object merge function, like the one jQuery uses:

```
function merge( first, second ) {
                var len = +second.length,
                        j = 0,
                        i = first.length;

                for ( ; j < len; j++ ) {
                        first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
                }

                first.length = i;

                return first;
        }
```

then just do

```
var newdata = merge(olddata, data);
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(newdata);
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L390